# Is grant_type=password still supported by DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

We were using grant_type=password. It stopped working now. Is DocuSign still supporting grant_type=password?

Comment: Welcome to SO. could you add some context to the question please ? See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This would be what we call "legacy auth" which is less secure and we highly recommend you move to OAuth.
As far as I know, it's still supported, if you're seeing an error - please let us know what error you are seeing. It's hard to help without additional information.